# Create and destroy objects automatically

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create and destroy objects in java automatically, while other processing is going on. How do I do it?

The objects which are created are added to a pool of objects (i.e. an array). Every object will have a time stamp, after which that object should be destroyed automatically. Similarly, some new objects should b created at random time and get added to the pool.

Probably I will have to use threads for concurrent processing. But the issue is, how do I create and destroy them automatically in the background while other processing in going on in java?

Comment: This smells of being an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question. Please tell what overlying behaviors you're trying to achieve as there may be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Why not simply give each object a Timer and have it "destroy" itself when time is up? I'm still not sure what difficulty you're having or what this is supposed to be for (overall).

Comment: I am trying to create a random number generator using a random pool of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can create new Thread which keeps on iterating Array of objects and checks there timestamp and remove objects whose timestamp consitions are met.

Comment: So continually poll, as opposed to using a timer -- why?